# Javascript - Display quiz questions based on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple javascript quiz set up on codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYNKJL

It displays one question per page and once you select an answer, you move onto the next question.  Whatever answer is selected is given the class "active" so I can get all the selected answers at the end of the quiz.

Each answer has a data-quizIndex of either 1 or 2.  When I collect all the "active" answers, I can see if they were answered data-quizIndex of 1 (first answer) or vice versa.

Anyways, up until this point, things are working great.  However, I am now attempting to do something else.  The user is directed to this quiz via a link, and the link will be one of the following

```
www.something.com/index.html?qa=0
www.something.com/index.html?qa=1
www.something.com/index.html?qa=2
```

The page they are coming from has a preview of question one which they can answer.  Using javascript, I need to get the qa value which shouldnt be a problem.  If qa is 0, the quiz starts from question 1 and nothing needs to be done.  If qa is 1 or 2, the quiz should start from question two and the active class for question 1 should be set to li with data-quizIndex 1 or data-quizIndex 2 (depending on the ga value).

In other words, if they answer question one from the page that redirects them to the quiz, I need to make it so question one is answered within the main quiz application.

Would this be possible and if so, what is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a `queryString` property into `location`, e.g:

```
if (typeof location.queryString === 'undefined') {
  Object.defineProperty(location, 'queryString', {
    get: function() {
      return location.search.slice(1).split('&').map(function(i) {
        var arr = i.split('=');
        var a = {};
        a[decodeURIComponent(arr[0])] = arr[1] ? decodeURIComponent(arr[1]) : void 0;
        return a;
      }).reduce(function(a, b) {
        var key = Object.keys(b)[0];
        a[key] = b[key];
        return a;
      });
    }
  });
}
```

And then, you can use it when the page is loaded, like this:

```
$(function() {
  var qa = location.queryString['qa'];
  if (qa === '1' || qa === '2') {
    $('.current .quiz-answer')[qa - 1].click();
  }
});
```

Since you want to simulate that the first question was answered, much better than repeating the code is to simulate as the user has clicked it. Take a look at your [updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdaeEy?qa=1).

Change the querystring, and loads it again, and you'll see that it's working like a charm! :)